# Exchange hash values without temporary variable

Tags: perl

I have two hash values a couple of levels deep in a data structure that I would like to exchange and then switch back later.

`$hashref->{$irrelevant}{$key1}` and `$hashref->{$irrelevant}{$key2}`

Since they are such long names, `($a, $b) = ($b, $a)` would be way too long for a single line of code.

Is there a way to do this elegantly, or am I stuck taking up three lines by exchanging with a temporary variable?

Comment: I suggest that you don't ask for "clever" ways, or you open yourself to all sorts of nastiness! (Not that they'll hold back even if you don't ask)

Comment: heh. I was just using it as shorthand for "a relatively common perl-ism that I just haven't heard of yet". I'm aware of the problem of writing code that is too clever.

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much understood that. I'm just warning that it may not be read as you intended!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You people who hide "irrelevant" data meanings aren't doing anyone any favours. We still have to write a solution, but it has to be in abstract terms that make no sense either to you or me!

The neatest way I can think of is with a pair of hash slices

```
my $irrelevant_href = $hashref->{$irrelevant};

@{$irrelevant_href}{$key1, $key2} = @{$irrelevant_href}{$key2, $key1};
```

Comment: Slices.  Nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a sub to make it clear what the long line full of symbols is doing.

```
sub swap { ($_[0], $_[1]) = ($_[1], $_[0]) }
```

And it also makes the line shorter.

```
swap($hashref->{$irrelevant}{$key1}, $hashref->{$irrelevant}{$key2});
```

You could even use

```
swap(@{ $hashref->{$irrelevant} }{ $key1, $key2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are far more grave sins in coding that declaring a lexical temp variable, but since you're asking let me throw an idea at you.

If you'll be doing any significant work with `$hashref->{$irrelevant}`, perhaps you should grab a copy of it specifically, to both make your code briefer for a maintenance programmer & cut out a level of dereferencing with every use.

For example:

```
# capture inner reference 'cause we'll be using it alot anyway...
my $ir_h_ref = $hashref->{$irrelevant};

#stuff here

# Do swap with shorter reference chain
( $ir_h_ref->{$key1}, $ir_h_ref->{$key2} ) = 
    ( $ir_h_ref->{$key2}, $ir_h_ref->{$key1} );
```

Now this new variable is probably not worth it *just* for the sake of the switch, but if you'll be doing much more with that hash in the same code block, it just may become attractive.